# Need help in treeview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I'm using Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView in my existing project, which is not working in all browsers(IE10). After searching in Bing/Google I came to know that this treeview is no more in use, and has been replaced by System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.  So I'm trying to replace the new treeview. Here I'm facing some issues with some properties. Can anyone tell me the equivalent properties for the new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView?

```
Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView TV1;

TV1.TreeNodeSrc = xml.OuterXml;

string index = TV1.SelectedNodeIndex;

txtObject.Text = TV1.GetNodeFromIndex(nodeIndex).Text;

tnDDAO = ((MSWebControls.TreeNode)TV1.GetNodeFromIndex(nodeIndex).Parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Use an XML data source and use that as the data source of the TreeView

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx) example in MSDN

2. To [get the index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenodecollection.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) of the selected node use

   TreeView TV1 = new TreeView();
   TV1.Nodes.IndexOf(TV1.SelectedNode).ToString();
3. To get the Text of the selected node use

   TreeView TV1 = new TreeView();
   txtObject.Text = TV1.SelectedNode.Text;
4. To find a node use [FindNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.findnode(v=vs.110).aspx) method

   TV1.FindNode

Comment: Hi, was this helpful? If so could you please vote and accept the answer?